# Treating site and year as an integrated factor

Tags: experiment-design, random-effects-model

I’m analyzing an experiment where we collected data across 4 different treatments. These treatments were replicated over two years.

In each year, we set-up the experiment at 2 different sites.

- In year 1, sites A and B.
- In year 2, sites A and C. (We used site A twice but switched out site B for a new location in year 2).

Typically, I would include site and year as factors in the model, each with two-levels. However, since this is unbalanced (we have different sites in yrs 1 and 2) I was thinking about creating a new variable called site-year, which combines the two into a single variable with four-levels (1A,1B,2A,2C).

Are there any benefits or drawbacks to considering site and year separately vs. as an integrated single variable?

Answer (score 1):

With your design it is not possible to estimate an interaction between site and year, so if you use an additive model with factors `site` and `year`, or one combined factor `siteyear`, the results will be the same. One fast way to see this is to do some experiments with R:

```r
N <- 5
year <- factor(rep(1:2, each=2*N))
site <- factor( c(rep(c("A", "B", "A", "C"), each=N))  )

siteyear <- interaction(site,  year)
```

and then calculating degrees of freedom this way, for three models:

```r
 Matrix::rankMatrix( model.matrix(  ~ site + year)  )

Matrix::rankMatrix( model.matrix(  ~ site * year)  )

Matrix::rankMatrix( model.matrix(  ~ siteyear)  )


[1] 4
attr(,"method")
[1] "tolNorm2"
attr(,"useGrad")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"tol")
[1] 4.440892e-15
> > 
[1] 4
attr(,"method")
[1] "tolNorm2"
attr(,"useGrad")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"tol")
[1] 4.440892e-15
> > 
[1] 4
attr(,"method")
[1] "tolNorm2"
attr(,"useGrad")
[1] FALSE
attr(,"tol")
[1] 4.440892e-15
```

Note the rank is 4 in all three cases, so for the results it does not really matter which you use.  Your tags indicate that you want a random effects model, I'm not sure that's a good idea with so few levels, but the conclusion is the same.

Comment: Thanks very much for the code and interpretation. Yes, sorry, I put random effects because I consider them random effects (biologically speaking, they're more like nuisance variables that I don't particularly care about), but you are correct that due to having only two-levels each this would not be appropriate.